# Product of sines general formula: $ \sin{x}\sin{2x}\sin{3x}...\sin{nx}$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, products

I've stumbled upon this product of sines:
$$ \sin{x}\sin{2x}\sin{3x}...\sin{nx}$$ 
I have to find a general formula for it. So far I tried to use the complex definition for the sine:
$$\sin{x}=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$$

$$\sin{x}\sin{2x}\sin{3x}...\sin{nx}=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{e^{kix}-e^{-kix}}{2i}=\frac{1}{(2i)^n}\prod_{k=1}^{n}e^{-kix}(e^{2kix}-1) \\
=\frac{1}{(2i)^n}\prod_{k=1}^{n}e^{-kix}\prod_{k=1}^{n}(e^{2kix}-1)$$
I got stuck when it came to this product:

$$ \prod_{k=1}^{n} {e^{2kix}-1}$$

What would you suggest? What should I do next?

Comment: For $\prod^n_{k=1}\sin xk$ where $x=1$, the product is given by:
$$\prod^n_{k=1}\sin 2k=2^{-(n+1)}i^ne^{-\frac12in(n+1)}(-1;e^{-i})_{n+1}(e^i;e^i)_n$$ Where $(-1;e^{-i})_{n+1}$ is a Pochhammer symbol

Comment: Discussed here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3710382/what-does-sin-x-cdot-sin-2x-cdot-sin-3x-cdot-cdot-sin-nx-equal-to/3710462#3710462