# What does $\sin x \cdot \sin 2x \cdot \sin 3x \cdot ... \cdot \sin nx$ equal to?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Problem: Find a general formula for:
>
> $$A = \sin x \cdot \sin 2x \cdot \sin 3x \cdot ... \cdot \sin nx$$

How do I come across with this? Or is there a way to simplify this? I tried to at least guess the formula but it seems complicated.

> Edit: From the comments, and some thoughts from me, I suspect that the answer to the above could be

### $$A = 2^{-n} \cdot i^n \cdot \prod_{k=1}^{n} \, \left(e^{-kix} - e^{kix}\right)$$

- Is this formula correct? (Can it be further simplified?)
- If yes, how do I prove it?

Comment: Are you given some direction on how the general formula should look? As it stands, $\sin x \cdot \sin 2x \cdot \cdots \sin nx$ is a general formula.

Comment: The same question was asked a couple of years ago [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2693896/409), with a bit more input from the asker. No answers, however, but comment gives a Pochhammer symbol representation when $x=1$. There are various other product-of-sines questions for specific values of $x$ (typically rational multiples of $\pi$).

Comment: @Charles Hudgins On my perspective, I think it should be some kind of sum of sin and/or cos functions (Based on the graph of $A$ on Desmos, as no bounds off were sound, so the formula couldn't contain either a fraction or a $\tan$/$\cot$)

Comment: [Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28x%29*sin%282*x%29*sin%283*x%29*sin%284*x%29*sin%285*x%29*sin%286*x%29*sin%287*x%29) gives sums of sines on odd $n$ and cosines on even $n$: $A_5(x)=\frac{1}{16} (\sin(x) + \sin(3 x) + \sin(5 x) - \sin(11 x) - \sin(13 x) + \sin(15 x))$, $A_4(x)=\frac{1}{8} (-\cos(6 x) - \cos(8 x) + \cos(10 x) + 1)$, $A_3=\frac{1}{4} (\sin(2 x) + \sin(4 x) - \sin(6 x))$

Comment: @Blue After re-reading the comment, I think that might be the answer, but we may also need to prove it right.

Comment: For $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}cos \frac{\phi}{2^n}$ is well known formula. For $sin$ may be helpful following info: for $x_n \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$ product $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin x_n}{x_n}$ converges together with series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_{n}^{2}$

Comment: hmm, the sum expression is very interesting. It seems that each trig function has the same coefficient up to a sign. But I can't detect an obvious pattern in the sign of the terms. My advice would be to stare at the problem until you detect a pattern in the signs and then set up a  proof by induction.

Comment: What makes you think you get anything simpler than the first expression? Is this a textbook exercise that suggests it? Or is this just something you're wondering about? ... I'll note that $\sin kx$ is given by $U_{k-1}(\cos x)\sin x$ where the $U$ is a [Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials). So, your $A$ can be written as $\sin^n x$ times the product of such $U$s. That doesn't seem simpler, though.

Comment: @Blue It's just something I'm curiously want to know. Thanks for your help btw.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, correct.

Euler's famous identity:  $$e^{i\phi} = \cos \phi + i \sin \phi $$ can also be written (replace $\phi$ with $-\phi$)

$$e^{-i\phi} = \cos \phi - i \sin \phi $$

Now take their difference these to see that $$\sin \phi = \frac{ e^{i \phi } - e^{-i\phi} }{2i}$$ which leads to your expression $(\phi = kx, \quad k=1,2,\cdots,n).$

Similarly, adding leads to $$\cos \phi = \frac{ e^{i \phi } + e^{-i\phi} }{2}.$$

You could multiply these binomials and see where that leads.  I don't know if you get something 'simpler' other than putting the result back into a form involving only sines and cosines.

**UPDATE**

Here are the results when applying the expression for $n=2$ and $n=3$ and then factoring to get the terms to involve only $\cos x$ and $\sin x$:

$$\sin x \cdot \sin 2x=\frac{1}{2} \cos x - \frac{1}{2} \cos^3 x + \frac{3}{2} \cos x \sin^2 x.$$

$$\sin x \cdot \sin 2x \cdot \sin 3x
=\frac{1}{2} \cos x \sin x
+\cos^3 x  \sin x
- \frac{3}{2} \cos^5~x \sin~x
-~\cos~x~\sin^3~x
+~5~\cos^3~x~\sin^3~x
-~\frac{3}{2}~\cos~x~\sin^5~x.$$

To get these forms, Let $p=e^{ix}$ and $q=e^{-ix}$ to
obtain a polynomial in $p$ and $q$.  Now factor to get terms involving only $p-q$ and $p+q$.  These terms are (up to a constant) $\sin x$ and $\cos x$.

Simpler than your expression for $A$?

Comment: Multiplying it out might let you express it as a sum of sines and cosines. If I were giving this problem, the goal would be to convert it from a product of trig functions to a sum of trig functions.

Comment: Right.  The result will be the sum of products of trigonometric functions.